# class destructor changes the program result

Tags: c++

the code bellow works ok if i comment the destructor and it print "Hello world"
if not commented it print "Hello" only !!
note i uses mingw 4.9 on windows xp 32bits 
and tha machine is very old pintume 4 1.8ghz

The strange thing about it is that this code works ok on other modern pc's , i only get this error on this old pc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct String{
public:
    String(const char * txt){
        len = strlen(txt);
        if (len > 0)
            buffer = (char*) malloc(len);
        strcpy(buffer,txt);
    }
    void add(const char * txt){
        realloc(buffer,len+strlen(txt));
        strcpy(buffer+len,txt);
        len += strlen(txt);
    }
    ~String(){ if (len > 0) free(buffer);} // if commented it works fine !!!
    char* get_ptr(){ return buffer;}
private:
    char * buffer;
    int len;    
};

int main(){
    String s("Hello");
    s.add(" World");
    printf(s.get_ptr());
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: `realloc` does not work in that way, you have to use its result. Also, using C allocation functions is weird in C++. You should also handle the len=0 case.

Comment: you are right , but i got the same result on both ways , also about c allocation funcs i think is ok if only used with primitives types

Comment: Apart from not using `realloc()` correctly, you are not allocating the correct length.   To hold a C-style string with functions like `strlen()`, `strcpy()`, etc it is necessary to include room for the terminating nul (byte with value `'\0'`), or the behaviour is undefined.   So you need to add one to the lengths (returned by `strlen()`) being passed to `malloc()` and `realloc()`.    Even better, use the standard library type `std::string` rather than rolling your own string type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::realoc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/c/realloc) has a return value, which returns the pointer to the reallocated memory area. This address can be the same as the input address, if there is enough free space behind the buffer, or can be a new address.

So if `realloc(buffer,len+strlen(txt));` returns a pointer that is different to the one stored in `buffer` then you will continue to work with an invalid pointer which results into undefined behavior. So for the PCs where it works, it might be because `realloc` returns the same pointer, or just because the undefined behavior does result in the "correct" result.

Changing the code (adding/removing the code form the destructor) will result in different memory layout which also can result in different outcomes of the undefined behavior.

Regardless of this, `realloc` is the wrong way to solve that problem in c++. You should use `std::string` here (or maybe `std::vector<char>` if don't want to have a string, but a buffer that you can resize).

Comment: thanks for the infos , i translated this program to free pascal , seems it works fine , i used ReallocMem provided by free pascal rtl , i don't know its internal code , but it should be the same as c realloc !!

Comment: seems buffer = realloc(buffer,len+strlen(txt)) solve the problem , thanks